# rewrite only subfolder not files

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I want to achieve is build urls like /profile1 /profile2 ...etc. which rewrites to profile.php?id=profile1

The code I am using currently is

```
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$              profile.php?p=$1    [NC,QSA,L]
```

It works as expected but problem is It also rewrites for urls like /sp.php?e=mybids

Those Urls are also redirected to profile.php, which I don't want it to happen.

Any help?

Comment: I would be more specific with your rule. `RewriteRule  ^/?profile([0-9]+)$` or group the `profile` too. The leading `/?` can be removed if you have `rewritebase` on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ profile.php?p=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the file does not exist, then redirect to profile.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?p=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Good luck